# Structure Map UnitOfWork multiple Generic Context EF

Tags: entity-framework, structuremap, dbcontext, unit-of-work, bounded-contexts

I have an UnitOfWork using Generic Context. How can I make the repository decide the concrete context to use using structure Map?

```
  public SomeRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWorkSomeContext)
        {
        _uowContext = unitOfWork.Context as ISomeContext;

        }

public class UnitOfWork: IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly IContext _context;

    public UnitOfWork(IContext context)
    {
        context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        _context = context;
    }
    public int Save()
    {
        return _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IContext Context
    {
        get { return _context; }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Doug

Comment: Do you mean that you want to tell SomeRepository to use SomeContext?
If so, that can be achieved using:
`For<SomeRepository>().Use<SomeRepository>().Ctor<IUnitOfWork>("unitOfWorkSomeContext").Is<SomeContext>();`